# Populating a ComboBox with a For loop from the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I am trying to populate my userform combobox with a list of part numbers after the user has selected the workstation on the previous user form.

My idea was to loop through the column, identify when the string matches the workstation and then add the cell in the column to the right (which turns out to be the product number)

My code looks like this so far:

```
If station = "MILL" Then
    With ComboBox1
    .AddItem "350SC109e.1"
    .AddItem "350 SC166"
    .AddItem "350 SC193"
    .AddItem "350 SC195"
    End With
End If

If station = "BRAKE" Then
    For i = 2 To ws1.Range("A265").End(xlUp).Row
    If ws1.Cells(i, 1) = "Brake" Then
       ComboBox1.AddItem ws1.Cells(i, 2)
    End If
    Next i
End If
```

The MILL is an example of a manually doing the thing I want to accomplish with the loop in the BRAKE if statement.

Comment: ComboBox1.AddItem ws1.Cells(i, 2).Value   As is it looks like youre trying to add a cell to the combo box.

Comment: So what would I need to write so it adds the value of the cell to the combo box, instead of the cell itself?

Comment: well thats my guess. you didnt provide information about what your issue is. What error(s) are you receiving?

Comment: No errors, just my combo box is empty when I select BRAKE on my first user form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i whipped this up real quick to demonstrate that I could get this to work in a loop. Youll have to adjust to fit your needs though. It did work flawlessly

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim txtVal As String

    If IsNull(TextBox1.Value) = False Then
        txtVal = TextBox1.Value
    Else
        txtVal = ""
    End If

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A21")
    Dim rcell As Range

    For Each rcell In rng.Cells
        If rcell.Value = txtVal Then
            With ComboBox1
                .AddItem rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End With
        End If
    Next rcell

End Sub
```